# Por qué salen los dos divs en vertical y no en horizontal?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

en el siguiente enlace justo en la sección  "you may also like" aparecen dos divs con dos productos que no salen en horizontal, por qué? debería ir en horizontal. :S

http://feelthegraph.000webhostapp.com/single-product.html

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código HTML y CSS relevante aquí mismo, porque es mucho más fácil tratar de ayudar y, además, si la página del enlace se modifica o elimina, la pregunta va a perder todo sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Como te indican en los comentarios. Es mejor que pongas el código en cuestión para que la gente que te quira ayudar lo tenga más facil.

Ahora bien, ahora mismo cuando estoy escribiendo esta respuesta, en la página se puede ver lo siguiente.

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                    <img class="img-single-product" src="assets/img/slide/slide10.jpg">                       
                  
                  </div>
  

                  <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                    <h4 class="price-product">Pic Title</h4> 
                    <div class="product-rating"><span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> 4.5 Stars</span> <span class="rating-review">35 Ratings &amp; 45 Reviews</span></div>
                    <div class="product-price"><span class="price-line-through"><h3 class="text-muted price-product">$200</h3></span><span><h3 class="price-product"> $120</h3></span></div>       
                    <div class="product-short-desc"><p>This is a short description where you can add some details about your product.</p></div>
                    <div class="product-sku"><sapn><strong>SKU: </strong>#21457832</sapn><br><sapn><strong>Categories: </strong><a href="store-html" class="ui-link">Nature, </a><a href="store-html" class="ui-link">Photos</a></sapn></div>
                    <hr style="width: 100%; color: #f4f4f4; height: 1px; background-color:#f4f4f4;">
                  
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        Share:<br>
                        <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

                      </div>    
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                      </div> 
                    </div>     
                  
                  </div>            


                    
                  <div id="exTab3" class="container">   
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active">
                          <a href="#1b" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-link">DESCRIPTION</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#2b" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-link">REVIEWS (3)</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                  
                        <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                          <div class="tab-pane active" id="1b">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error blanditiis a, deserunt magnam pariatur quam suscipit quae. Veniam, deserunt reprehenderit quasi hic recusandae itaque omnis fugiat animi architecto facilis repellendus. Commodi dolorem, eius consectetur. Amet maiores nemo at nobi s aspernatur velit, sequi odio, a veritatis inventore autem esse provident in? Placeat, sunt!</p>
                            <p>Iste assumenda, vitae, aliquam excepturi libero quia ullam quisquam tenetur id sint labore. Pariatur praesentium velit, fugit facere maxime voluptates optio qui? Quidem obcaecati necessitatibus rem aspernatur, mollitia, assumenda explicabo numquam minus eos sapiente totam dicta, laborum dolorum! Vitae distinctio quos non ut fugiat.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar1.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Martin Luther Caint</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar2.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Dr. O'Donnell</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar3.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Agatha Riviera</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="ymal">
                          <center><h5 class="price-product">You may also like</h5></center>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                          
                        <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                          <a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Designs, </a><a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pictures</a><br>
                          <a class="pictitle-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pic Title </a><p></p>
                          
                              <div class="hovereffect">
                                <img src="assets/img/slide/slide5.jpg" class="principal-image-1 principal-image d-block w-100" alt="...">    
                                <div class="overlay">
                                        <p class="icon-links">
                                            <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                              <i class="icon-product fas fa-random" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                              <i class="icon-product far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                          
                          
      
                          <div class="row">
                          <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                            <i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                            <span class="title-product-span">$120</span><span class="sub-title-product-span">$200</span>
                          </div>    
                          <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                            <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                          </div> 
                          </div>                              
                        </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                      <a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Designs, </a><a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pictures</a><br>
                      <a class="pictitle-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pic Title </a><p></p>
                      
                          <div class="hovereffect">
                            <img src="assets/img/slide/slide9.jpg" class="principal-image-1 principal-image d-block w-100" alt="...">    
                            <div class="overlay">
                                    <p class="icon-links">
                                        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                          <i class="icon-product fas fa-random" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                          <i class="icon-product far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                      
  
                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                        <span class="title-product-span">$120</span><span class="sub-title-product-span">$200</span>
                      </div>    
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                      </div> 
                      </div>                              
                    </div>    
             
             
                  </div>
```

Si te fijas bien, el segundo elemento que tendría que estar en "You may also like" se encuentra fuera del row de "You may also like".

Debería quedar algo así para que ambos estén en la misma linea.

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                    <img class="img-single-product" src="assets/img/slide/slide10.jpg">                       
                  
                  </div>
  

                  <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                    <h4 class="price-product">Pic Title</h4> 
                    <div class="product-rating"><span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> 4.5 Stars</span> <span class="rating-review">35 Ratings &amp; 45 Reviews</span></div>
                    <div class="product-price"><span class="price-line-through"><h3 class="text-muted price-product">$200</h3></span><span><h3 class="price-product"> $120</h3></span></div>       
                    <div class="product-short-desc"><p>This is a short description where you can add some details about your product.</p></div>
                    <div class="product-sku"><sapn><strong>SKU: </strong>#21457832</sapn><br><sapn><strong>Categories: </strong><a href="store-html" class="ui-link">Nature, </a><a href="store-html" class="ui-link">Photos</a></sapn></div>
                    <hr style="width: 100%; color: #f4f4f4; height: 1px; background-color:#f4f4f4;">
                  
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        Share:<br>
                        <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a class="a-social-product ui-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

                      </div>    
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                      </div> 
                    </div>     
                  
                  </div>            


                    
                  <div id="exTab3" class="container">   
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active">
                          <a href="#1b" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-link">DESCRIPTION</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#2b" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-link">REVIEWS (3)</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                  
                        <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                          <div class="tab-pane active" id="1b">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error blanditiis a, deserunt magnam pariatur quam suscipit quae. Veniam, deserunt reprehenderit quasi hic recusandae itaque omnis fugiat animi architecto facilis repellendus. Commodi dolorem, eius consectetur. Amet maiores nemo at nobi s aspernatur velit, sequi odio, a veritatis inventore autem esse provident in? Placeat, sunt!</p>
                            <p>Iste assumenda, vitae, aliquam excepturi libero quia ullam quisquam tenetur id sint labore. Pariatur praesentium velit, fugit facere maxime voluptates optio qui? Quidem obcaecati necessitatibus rem aspernatur, mollitia, assumenda explicabo numquam minus eos sapiente totam dicta, laborum dolorum! Vitae distinctio quos non ut fugiat.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar1.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Martin Luther Caint</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar2.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Dr. O'Donnell</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="media">
                              <img src="assets/img/avatar3.jpg" class="mr-3 avatar" alt="...">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <strong><p>Average quality for the price<span style="float: right;"><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br></span></p></strong>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                                <p>Agatha Riviera</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="ymal">
                          <center><h5 class="price-product">You may also like</h5></center>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                          
                        <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                          <a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Designs, </a><a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pictures</a><br>
                          <a class="pictitle-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pic Title </a><p></p>
                          
                              <div class="hovereffect">
                                <img src="assets/img/slide/slide5.jpg" class="principal-image-1 principal-image d-block w-100" alt="...">    
                                <div class="overlay">
                                        <p class="icon-links">
                                            <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                              <i class="icon-product fas fa-random" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                              <i class="icon-product far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                          
                          
      
                          <div class="row">
                          <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                            <i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                            <span class="title-product-span">$120</span><span class="sub-title-product-span">$200</span>
                          </div>    
                          <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                            <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                          </div> 
                          </div>                              
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-md-6 product-div">
                      <a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Designs, </a><a class="category-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pictures</a><br>
                      <a class="pictitle-store ui-link" href="category.html">Pic Title </a><p></p>
                      
                          <div class="hovereffect">
                            <img src="assets/img/slide/slide9.jpg" class="principal-image-1 principal-image d-block w-100" alt="...">    
                            <div class="overlay">
                                    <p class="icon-links">
                                        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                          <i class="icon-product fas fa-random" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="ui-link">
                                          <i class="icon-product far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                      
  
                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="color: #fdba2d;" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                        <span class="title-product-span">$120</span><span class="sub-title-product-span">$200</span>
                      </div>    
                      <div class="down-image col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="float-right btn btn-add-to-cart ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add to cart</button>
                      </div> 
                      </div>                              
                    </div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Como no has dado ningún detalle más, no sabemos si dicho html lo estás generando de manera dinámica mediante php, javascript, etc o solamente lo que tienes es html, entonces no podemos ayudarte mucho más.

Un saludo

Comment: Era eso, perfecto gracias!

Comment: @vlaiz considera arreglar tu pregunta para evitar el cierre de la misma